# Getting all IP addresses of a hostname

Tags: perl, nslookup

I'm trying to get all the IP addresses for a host.

This is the nslookup output:

```
>>nslookup site.com

Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   site.com
Address: 1.1.1.1
Name:   site.com
Address: 2.2.2.2
```

I tried this code:

```
use Socket;
use Data::Dumper;
my $name = "site.com";
@addresses = gethostbyname($name)   or die "Can't resolve $name: $!\n";
@addresses = map { inet_ntoa($_) } @addresses[4 .. $#addresses];
print Dumper(\@addresses);
```

And this is the output:

```
['1.1.1.1'];
```

Anyway to get both `1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2`?

Comment: Note that `perldoc -f gethostbyname` tells us: _"Make sure "gethostbyname" is called in SCALAR context and that its return value is checked for definedness."_  Your code sample does neither.

Comment: @JamesEKeenan That's for resolving a hostname to a single IP address when you don't care about all the other information a list context `gethostbyname` returns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Net::DNS::Resolver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::DNS::Resolver) to get the IPv4 addresses (A records) for a hostname:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use feature 'say';

use Net::DNS::Resolver;

my $res = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;

my $name = 'stackoverflow.com';
my $q = $res->query($name);

if ($q){
    print "$name has the following IPv4 addresses:\n";
    for ($q->answer){
        say $_->address if $_->type eq 'A';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
stackoverflow.com has the following IPv4 addresses:
151.101.65.69
151.101.193.69
151.101.1.69
151.101.129.69
```

Comment: That gives you all of the IPs that nameserver hands out, which is probably what OP wanted, but it's not the same as all IP addresses of a hostname.

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol `cnn.com`'s authoritative name server hands out the same IP addresses. Please clarify what you're getting at.

Comment: I get completely different answers for www.cnn.com querying from California and New York. What I mean is DNS tricks can be used to direct you to a particular instance or set of instances, and an exhaustive list of IP addresses is not practical to determine as an outsider.

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol Examples are desired.

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol Test against authoritative sources; not against ad-placing, DNS hijacking ISPs.

Comment: Look at the first example in the section called "stupid dns tricks": https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1647302

Comment: I understand. I've met Paul Vixie at ARIN conferences. There's many ambiguities. If you have a better answer for OP, write one ;)

Comment: I think your answer is what OP wanted, but OP's question is vague and for posterity I wanted to point that out.

Comment: Personally, I would like to see your digression. Look at my [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/author/STEVEB) page for my email address. This is a Perl-esque question, but I'm still interested (although kind of detached) from DNS stuff. Love to discuss.

Comment: How many IP addresses do companies like Facebook or Google have (indicatively) in order to serve billions of requests? Thank you!

Comment: @tonix Billions of requests can be served from a single IP address...

Answer (score 0):

Simple pure perl to print the IP of the domain  `stackoverflow.com` :

```
use Socket;
print join'.',unpack('C4',inet_aton('stackoverflow.com'));
print "\n";
```